# mingw vs msvc on implicit conversion of string literals

Tags: c++, c++17, string-literals

I have a `std::variant` of different types including `int32_t`, `int64_t`, `float`, `double`, `std::string` and `bool`.
When I assign a string literal (`const char*`, which is not present in this variant), I assumed it will be implicitly converted to `std::string` and it worked as I expected with `MinGW (9.0.0 64-bit)`. But with `MSVC (2019 64-bit)` it implicitly converted to `bool`.
If I explicitly converts it to std::string and then assign it to variant it works fine with both compilers.

Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <variant>

#if defined(__MINGW64__) || defined(__MINGW32__)
#define CMP_NAME "[ MinGW ]"
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
#define CMP_NAME "[ MSVC ]"
#else
#define CMP_NAME "[ Others ]"
#endif

using KInt32 = int32_t;
using KInt64 = int64_t;
using KFloat = float;
using KDouble = double;
using KString = std::string;
using KBoolean = bool;

using Variant = std::variant<
    KInt32      /*0*/,
    KInt64      /*1*/,
    KFloat      /*2*/,
    KDouble     /*3*/,
    KString     /*4*/,
    KBoolean    /*5*/
>;

int main()
{
    //passing a const char* to Variant [target is to initialize as KString]
    Variant var = "ABCDE";
    std::cout << "Build With Compiler Set " CMP_NAME << std::endl;
    std::cout << "index = " << var.index() << std::endl;
    try{
        KString &str = std::get<KString>(var);
        std::cout << "\t[string = " << str << "]" << std::endl;
    }
    catch(const std::exception &e){
        std::cout << "\t[exception = " << e.what() << "]" << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Here's the output
With MinGW 9.0.0

```
     Build With Compiler Set [ MSVC ]
     index = 5
          [exception = bad variant access]
```

With MSVC 2019

```
Build With Compiler Set [ MinGW ]
index = 4
    [string = ABCDE]
```

Index 4 denotes to `KString` (aka `std::string`) and 5 denotes to `KBoolean` (aka `bool`).
***So my question is why both compilers are giving different results?***

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior of variant changed *for this exact case* in C++20.
See [What is the best way to disable implicit conversion from pointer types to bool when constructing an std::variant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64249832/what-is-the-best-way-to-disable-implicit-conversion-from-pointer-types-to-bool-w) for a longer discussion.

Comment: Thanks. I saw that post and the bug mentioned was similar to mine. Actually I have a wrapper class. But just to save some writing I made template constructors so it was accessing it directly. Now I made another constructor for const char*, it converts string literal to KString explicitly and then it is assigned to the variant. And now it's working as I want.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like bug in standard library which has been fixed.

I've wrote this test:

```cpp
#include "catch2/catch_all.hpp"
#include <variant>

TEST_CASE("std::variant literal conversion") {
    std::variant<int, double, std::string, bool> var;
    CHECK(var.index() == 0);

    var = 1;
    CHECK(var.index() == 0);
    CHECK(std::holds_alternative<int>(var));

    var = 1.0;
    CHECK(var.index() == 1);
    CHECK(std::holds_alternative<double>(var));

    var = std::string{"foo"};
    CHECK(var.index() == 2);
    CHECK(std::holds_alternative<std::string>(var));

    var = true;
    CHECK(var.index() == 3);
    CHECK(std::holds_alternative<bool>(var));

    var = "foo";
    CHECK(var.index() == 2);
    CHECK(std::holds_alternative<std::string>(var));
}
```

And it fails on GCC 9.4 and Clang 10.0.1 and it is fine on GCC 10.1 and Clang 11.0.

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/9rnr4s58j)

Comment: It really looks like a bug. I was only using GCC/MinGW so didn't get to know about this problem but yesterday with MSVC I got strange results. Now fixed it.

Comment: Note there a 3 major implementations of standard library. `msvc` has own implementation, `gcc` and `clang` can operate on two version of it: `libstdc++` and `libc++`, so each can have different set of bugs.